# after copying files. Any method to check no files missing vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hi I am trying to copy some files from one folder to other folder. For example, 147 tiff image files. I use

```
  My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(source,destination,true) m.
```

But i want to check the 147 files are all in my destination folder. What if it is missing? any method to check that all the time after copying? Or should i use another way to do copy, not copy directory, copy files by files? this is a safer way, but takes more time.

Can anyone write a piece of codes for me to do this? cheers

Comment: You can assume that if the copy does not throw an exception then it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link should help:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546137.aspx

In this code they first test to see if the file lists are identical. If not, they list what's different.